# Find which screen window is on

Tags: java, swing, window, screen

How can I detect which screen a JFrame is located on? I need to find the screen and resize the frame to make sure it is not larger than the relevant screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose you mention, you can call `frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds()`. If you actually want to query other things about the display device itself, use `frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice()` (as well as other methods in the `GraphicsConfiguration`), which might get you some interesting things.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Toolkit`

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());  
int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());
```

and after it just

```
frame.setSize(xSize,ySize);
```

If you want to maximize frame just call next method

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Comment: But what if there are 5 screens, all with different resolutions? Which screen size do I grab?

Comment: if you use `frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` won't it just make it as big as whatever screen it is on?  You shouldn't really have to worry that it is bigger than whatever screen it is appearing on.  Unless I am just wrong.. which is entirely possible.

Comment: If you have 5 screens this code has to executed for each screen, best practice is execute this code during initialization of frame.